# Printing text with spacing recursively

Tags: java, recursion

This is an assignment for school.  I am having trouble understanding how I can print the following recursively:

```
This was written by call number 2.
 This was written by call number 3.
  This was written by call number 4.
   This ALSO written by call number 4.
  This ALSO written by call number 3.
 This ALSO written by call number 2.
This ALSO written by call number 1.
```

I'm not sure if I am supposed to be illustrating a loop vs. recursion or if there is a way to print all of this recursively. Additionally, how would I go about reversing the recursion call so it starts from 4 as per the example output?

This is my current output.

```
This was written by call number 2.
This was written by call number 3.
This was written by call number 4.
This ALSO written by call number 1.
  This ALSO written by call number 2.
   This ALSO written by call number 3.
    This ALSO written by call number 4.
```

There is no spacing implemented in the for loop yet b/c I'm not sure if that part is also supposed to be recursive.

My code:

```
public class Recursion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("This was written by call number " + i + ".");
    }
    recurse(4);
  }

  public static void recurse(int n) {
    String temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp += " ";
    }

    if (n < 2) {
        System.out.println("This ALSO written by call number " + n + ".");
    } 
    else {
        recurse(n - 1);
        System.out.println(temp + "This ALSO written by call number " + n + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: to make it easier, I'd recommend using 2 distinctive functions. One printing the line after the recursive call, another printing it prior to.

Comment: @MichaelJames No, it's not necessary to use 2 functions.  I'm in the middle of writing an answer...

Comment: You can do it with a single function and then probably need to either hardcode 4, or keep it as a second parameter. Normally I'd write the recursion counting backwards - with a single function you'd need to increase the counter. Either way the recursive function is around 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurse(1);
}

public static void recurse (int n) {
    if (n==5) return;
    String temp="";
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) temp += " ";
    if (n!=1) {
     System.out.println(temp + "This was written by call number " + n + ".");
    }
    recurse(n+1);
    temp=" ";
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) temp += " ";
    System.out.println(temp + "This ALSO was written by call number " + n + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to writing most recursive programs (especially the ones you're given as assignments) is to look for a larger problem that contains a similar but smaller occurrence of the same problem.

In your case, the "larger problem" would be to print the 6 lines that start and end with "call number 2".  That is, print lines for call numbers 2 through 4.  The way to do this is: print the first line that says "call number 2", *solve the problem to print the 4 lines for call numbers 3 through 4*, and print the last line that says "call number 2".  The part in the middle is the smaller occurrence of the same problem.  That's going to be the recursive call.

Since your larger problem is going to start with "call number 2", and your smaller problem is going to start with the call number that's one higher, I'd recommend arranging things so that you call `recurse(n+1)` instead of `recurse(n-1)`.  If you do that, you'll need a second parameter so that you know when to stop recursing--something like `recurse(n+1, last)`.

Hopefully this will be enough to get you thinking on the right track.

Comment: I did think about the need to "reverse my recursion" by using `n+1` but i got a stack overflow b/c it didn't have a second parameter.  Thanks. I will see what I can come up with..  However, just for clarification sake, can I print the first part recursively: `This was written by call number n` or should I just be using a for loop for that like I am currently?  Edit: you said the "six lines" so I assume I can do everything they are asking for w/o a for loop.  Having trouble understanding how I would put ALSO in there just using one function..

Comment: @MichaelJames The "larger problem" for call number 2 is 6 lines; the smaller problem is 4 lines.  That means that your function for call number 2 will print both the first and the last line, with the recursion in between.  I think if you think about it, you'll figure out the answer to your last question.

Comment: AH!!  I did not think about it that way!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurse(1, true, 1);
}

public static void recurse(int n, boolean loop, int add) {
    String temp = "";
    String out = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp += " ";
    }

    if (add > 0) {
        out = temp + "This was written by call number ";
    } else {
        out = temp + "This ALSO written by call number ";
    }

    if (n == 1 && !loop) {
        System.out.println(out + n + ".");
        return;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        recurse(n+add, false, add);
    } else if (n == 5) {
        add = add - 2 * add;
        recurse(n+add, false, add);
    } else {
        System.out.println(out + n + ".");
        recurse(n+add, false, add);
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution should be much simpler

Comment: Judging by your name, it'd be 00:57 which is not that late, i.e. I believe I live east of your location

Comment: Lol guys, anyways I tested this code and it produced the correct answer. Since this is a school project I don't think we should be giving him the "simplest solution" (@bestsss) anyway. Mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is quite a straightforward solution. Also pay attention how you can easily get the indent string (via substring). The recursion is as simple as it gets: print the number, enter the function with a larger number if below the max, then follow back.

```
   class R{
      static final String spaces="                                 ";
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec3(1,4);
      }
      private static void rec3(int i, int max) {
        if (i>1) System.out.printf("%sThis was written by call number: %d%n", spaces.substring(0, i-1), i);  
        if (i<max) rec3(i+1, max);
        System.out.printf("%sThis was ALSO written by call number: %d%n", spaces.substring(0, i-1), i);     
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help.  I ended up modifying the solution from @JoseLuis a little bit.

```
public class Recursion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurse(1, 5);
  }

  public static void recurse(int n, int max) {
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp += " ";
    }
    if (n == max) {
        return;
    }
    if (n != 1) {
        System.out.println(temp + "This was written by call number " + n + ".");
    }
    recurse(n + 1, max);
    System.out.println(temp + "This ALSO was written by call number " + n + ".");
  }
}
```